# Why was this Off-Topic flag declined on a non-programming Excel PivotTable question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Yesterday I flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803305/pivottable-to-show-values-not-sum-of-values) for being Off-Topic (more specifically blatantly off-topic, nothing to do with programming) as the question doesn't mention any programming whatsoever not even a reference to a macro or VBA, and neither does the correlated answer, the answer is essentially a step by step using standard Excel features. So due to no programming mentioned I flagged as such.

However it didn't take long for the flag to be *declined* not even disputed a straight declined with no correlated message with it.[image]

I asked this in the SOCVR room and they could not give a definitive answer at the time and @StephenKennedy found it "interesting" the flag was declined and not disputed. @SurajRao also provided the [close vote review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/19919990) as well.

Was I wrong to flag this?

If I was correct in flagging this (without intentionally pointing blame), then the only thing I can think of is the reviewers didn't read the question and answer fully and just looked at age and score of the question.

Comment: [The SOCVR transcript of that discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42798961#42798961)

Comment: It was an entirely [normal review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/19919990), all three reviewers voted to keep it open.

Comment: old question, upvoted, starred, useful answers one of which has considerate effort behind it. I can understand why people would disagree with closing it, it has all the hallmarks of "good!". The only thing it has going against it is that it really belongs on a different site, but migration is no longer possible.

Comment: @Gimby don't get me wrong the answer is a good one and very detailed, but the question doesn't belong here, which is why I flagged it

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I added a close vote to it, but I'm reasoning why people would choose to decline the flag. And I fully understand why.

Comment: Short answer is anytime you vote to close an old question, you run the risk of getting declined.  When an old question isn't actively causing harm (bad/outdated answers, attracting bad or spam answers) there is a good chance people will want to keep it around.  Your close votes are better spent on newer questions.  And FYI - there are several thousand open 0+ scoring questions with the [tag:excel] tag [that mention the word "pivot"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+pivot+closed%3A0+votes%3A0...).  Do you want to try to close all of them?

Comment: It actually got put on hold 45min ago as off topic anyway.

Comment: I've never much liked this "well it has good content, so even though it's off-topic we'll leave it here." Those come back to bite us when we close a question for being off-topic, and the ask complains and links to a prominent example of an off-topic question that isn't closed.

Comment: To put @psubsee2003 comment in perspective: of the questions tagged [excel] which includes pivot there are 1537 with positive score, 2634 with 0 score and 252 with negative score.

Comment: @pnuts You scaled down, right?

Comment: The Q referenced probably should have been closed as _to broad_ rather than _general computing_. The Meta Q is valid, is an Excel Q whose answer  _may_ involve vba, or formulas, or both, or neither, On Topic? (Other Q quality criteria being satisfied)

Comment: @punts I agree.  That's why I think a Meta Q might be useful.  See what the wider community thinks.  One example: _how do I do X in Excel with Formulas/vba_ which gets answered _use a Pivot Table_  or _use an External Data Connection_

Comment: In the mean time, the question has been reopened through [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/19937973). Perhaps hold off on further closure before there's more consensus? Bouncing this question between close and reopen doesn't seem like a sensible thing to do.

Comment: In order to get a good discussion about what is appropriate for Excel the title of the Question should be changed, or a new question opened. FWIW I see both sides of the argument and lean towards accepting this type of question on Stack Overflow. But if one does, the tag info needs to be adjusted (it's mentioned in the long version, but not the short one).

Comment: @Cindy Meister: I've edited the title.

Comment: @pnuts: My editing someone else's question does not imply or reflect my endorsement of their view. As you've stated, the title represents *their* view - I'm just clarifying it on their behalf.

Comment: @pnuts: I'm aware of that, but I wasn't aware that it applied to edits. I've been editing posts I disagree and agree with for some time and so far no one else has taken my edits to mean that I support the views expressed therein (except when mistaking me to be the author). I've also clarified off-topic questions in edits and comments while reiterating that they're off-topic. I suspect many other moderators have done the same. The only exception is when there is a clear conflict of interest, e.g. editing posts that are *about* the moderator in question - and that applies to anyone really.

Comment: @pnuts: I can't prioritize questions I was never aware of :) But if we're going to talk priorities, I'm going to go back to whatever non-SO thing I was doing at the time, since this is getting off-topic now and I never intended to do more than a drive-by edit because I had like 5 minutes to spare.

Comment: @pnuts (and @BoltClock) apparently the need to discuss this isn't so great, at least, not with this title. I suppose it would need to be a separate discussion - if any at all.

Comment: @pnuts I missed those discussions - thanks for letting me know they took place. FWIW I have no trouble with these "borderline features". We have similar in Word, as well, with field codes.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts I wasn't around / active so long ago, which explains why this is new to me.